# Parsing error: ecmaVersion must be a number. Received value of type string instead

Tags: import, ecma

I'm getting the error: Parsing error: ecmaVersion must be a number. Received value of type string instead. It causing the first import of all my files to be underlined in red. As far as I know it hasn't affected my code at all, but the error is annoying. Does anyone know how I can fix it?